# Static files aren't loading after changing STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS in django

Tags: python, django

I was following a tutorial on setting STATIC_ROOT using a CDN for my satic files but I've decide I'd like to serve my static files on the same server where my django app is served.  I tried changing to the new settings below and I ran manage.py collectstatic and now the static files aren't loading.  What am I doing wrong? This is w/ django 1.9

new settings not working:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

old settings working:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    ]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you keeping your static files?

If you are keeping them in `BASE_DIR/static then it is important to include the same`STATICFILES_DIRS` as you have in the second settings file.

If you having your static files spread throughout your different apps then you want to make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder` is added to your [STATICFILES_FINDERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS).

The point of `collectstatic` is to get static files from all your various apps (admin,polls,ect.) and move them to your static root for serving.  You also need to make sure that your `STATIC_ROOT` is [being served](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/).

It's also probably not a good idea to have you STATIC_ROOT pointing to somewhere inside your BASE_DIR - usually this will not be served statically by your web server.

Comment: My static files are in BASE_DIR/static. When I add back the STATICFILES_DIRS setting and set STATIC_ROOT= '', I get django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Comment: I assume your running this on the test server for now? Or is this in development? Try setting STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_root") and keeping the STATICFILES_DIRS setting.  If you are running `manage.py runserver` you shouldn't need to run `collectstatic`

Comment: This is testing through manage.py runserver for now. Adding the above STATIC_ROOT setting would add a folder outside my BASE_DIR. So when I run collectstatic on production, it should copy all the static files from BASE_DIR/static to ../static_root and I specify that static_root folder in apache or nginx?

Comment: Yes, you can keep it in your BASE_DIR if you want. But as long as you never run `collectstatic` it wont be created.  I think it's important to have STATIC_ROOT named something different from where you keep your static files for development, so os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root') would work as well.